# Logstash with XML file

Tags: elasticsearch, jenkins, logstash, fileinputstream

We are using logstash to read an xml file. This xml file is generated when a Jenkins pipeline build commences and is written to with build data during the pipeline execution. We use file input mode 'read'.

**CURRENT BEHAVIOR:**
The xml file is created when the Jenkins pipeline starts. Logstash discovers this xml file, reads it, logs it, and does not return to the xml file again.

**PROBLEM:**
Logstash has read the xml file prematurely and misses all the subsequent data that is written to it.

**DESIRED BEHAVIOR:**
Logstash allows us to apply some condition to tell it when to read the xml file. Ideally a trigger would tell logstash the xml file is completed and ready to be read and logged.

We want this to work with file input mode 'read'. The xml file is written to for around 1.5 hours.
Is there a filter, plugin or some other functionally that will allow logstash to return to the xml file when it is modified?

Comment: Perhaps set the `close_older` parameter of the file input plugin to more than 1.5 hours? ([doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file-close_older))

Comment: **close_older** doesn't change the behavior of how the file is read. It is still only read once, when xml the file is created.